# Как достать картинку из PDF?

Tags: pdf, php, парсер

Что есть:

```
Array
(
[0] => 5
[1] => Array
    (
        [/Subtype] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /Image
            )

        [/Intent] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /RelativeColorimetric
            )

        [/Length] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1431417
            )

        [/Filter] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /FlateDecode
            )

        [/Name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /X
            )

        [/BitsPerComponent] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 8
            )

        [/ColorSpace] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /DeviceCMYK
            )

        [/Width] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 935
            )

        [/DecodeParms] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [/Columns] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 935
                            )

                        [/Predictor] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 15
                            )

                        [/BitsPerComponent] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 1
                            )

                        [/Colors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 4
                            )
                    )
            )

        [/Height] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 541
            )

        [/Type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => /XObject
            )
    )
)
```

И есть `$stream`, где есть source картинки.

Проблема: простой метод `gzubcompress($stream)` что-то выдает, но это не картинка. Походу ее еще надо как-то преобразовать.

Прилагаю и сами данные для проверки корректности получения массива:

```
29 0 obj
<</Subtype/Image/Intent/RelativeColorimetric/Length 1431417/Filter/FlateDecode/Name/X/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceCMYK/Width 935/DecodeParms<</Columns 935/Predictor 15/BitsPerComponent 1/Colors 4>>/Height 541/Type/XObject>>stream
```

Прбовал сохранять в формат jpeg, jp2, jpg - картинка не открывается. Пробовал Imagick открывать, который умеет без расширения по внутренностям определять что это за .... Валит исключение.(

Версия pdf 1.7
На доку не посылать - уже нашел, читаю, не вгоняю!)

Если поможете, выложу парсер pdf! Текст уже достается.)

Comment: Пахнет PNG форматом (Predictor 15)
А можно исходник потока как-нибудь глянуть?

Comment: увы, не png (не gif, не tiff).
Выложил пару строк из расшифрованного куса стрим и не расшифрованного. Хотя в теории фильтр FlateDecode говорит о том, что надо применить gzuncompress.

Не расшифрованный кусок: H‰TWiP[ЧЦ.Ѕ'Ѓ$Рю$$Ўf

Расшифрованный кусок: &й(Й+и)Д*йШ*лЭ'тб)сЯ)с

Доку походу придется дочитать!) Нашел там полезные строки, но пока результата нет. Надо использовать colorspace значение для определения метода встраивания изображения. deviceCmyk - значит что у нас 4 цвета по 8 бит на значение. То есть каждые 4 8битных значения определяют точку. Как из этого собрать картинку?

Comment: Беру свои слова обратно - это PNG. По крайней мере мануал упорно твердит на это. Остается вопрос: как этот стрим запихнуть в gzinflate. Отрезание двух символов в начале не помогает, и дает результат H(делаю unpack('v',2 символа)). В инете пишут если выдает x - то обрезание двух символов канает для получения картинки.

Comment: А ты не пробовал добавлять какие-то байты в заголовок перед распаковкой потока?
31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 (Это с адобовского форума)

Comment: Пробовал, увы чего то не хватает - картинка не выводится. Именно эти я и брал значения и стого же адобовского форума.(

Answer (score 2):

В Зенд фреймворке это реализовано вот тут:

```
abstract class Zend_Pdf_Filter_Compression implements Zend_Pdf_Filter_Interface
{
    protected static function _applyDecodeParams($data, $params){
    ...
```

в нём есть декодирование и в том числе PNG

**UPD.** А тут вообще всё симпатично

```
class Zend_Pdf_Filter_Compression_Flate extends Zend_Pdf_Filter_Compression
{
    public static function decode($data, $params = null)
    {
```

Comment: Попробую. Только вот zend я не использую в проекте. Где бы внутренности найти этого метода (чтобы на чистом php написать)?

Comment: Вот что нашел из полезного: http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Pdf/Filter/Compression/Flate.php.source.html

Остается найти _applyEncodeParams из предка.

Comment: Я сейчас завизжу от счастья!))) Шутка. Вот и база: http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Pdf/Filter/Compression.php.source.html
Пока плюсую! Огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: Радость была не долгой. Картинка расшифровывается, но что из этого получается, я не знаю. Итак: применил зендовский алгоритм для декодирования с параметрами. Пытался сохранять во все известные мне форматы, но файл не открывается. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: Попробуй интерпретировать получившееся как ppm (Portable Pixelmap, image/x-portable-pixmap) (как минимум IrfanView и ACDSee умеют открывать это). Может и получится.

Если нет - тогда pdfimages. Она извлекает содержимое в как раз в этом формате. Причём извлекает отменно - сейчас скормил ему кучу pdf-ок - извлеклось вообще всё, даже то, чего в них не было :-) Ну и работаеть оно будет естественно шустрее чем PHPшная реализация...